# Reading contents of blocks directly in a datanode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

In HDFS , the blocks are distributed among the active nodes/slaves. The content of the blocks are simple text so is there any way to see read or access the blocks present in each data node ?

Answer (score 0):

As an entire file or to read a single block (say block number 3) out of sequence?

You can read the file via various mechanisms including the Java API but you cannot start reading in the middle of the file (for example at the start of block 3).

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop reads a block of data and feeds each line to the mapper for further processing. Also, the Hadoop clients gets the blocks related to a file from different Data Nodes before concatenating them. So, it should be possible to get the data from a particular block.

Hadoop Client might be a good place to start with to look at the code. But, HDFS provides file system abstraction. Not sure what the requirement would be for reading the data from a particular block.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have ssh access (and appropriate permissions) to the datanodes, you can `cd` to the path where the blocks are stored and read the blocks stored on that node (e.g., do a `cat BLOCK_XXXX`). The configuration parameter that tells you where the blocks are stored is `dfs.datanode.data.dir`, which defaults to `file://${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data`. More details [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml).

Caveat: the block names are coded by HDFS depending on their internal block ID. Just by looking at their names, you cannot know to which file a block belongs.

Finally, I assume you want to do this for debugging purposes or just to satisfy your curiosity. Normally, there is no reason to do this and you should just use the HDFS web-UI or command-line tools to look at the contents of your files.